# Class that is supposed to count neighboring cells in a 2D array doesn't count properly in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, counting

I've written a class in C# that counts neighboring live cells in a 2D array. Let's say I have an array like this

```
int[,] array = new int[8, 8]
{
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
    {3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3},
    {3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3},
    {3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3},
    {3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3},
    {3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
};
```

In this array `0` are dead cells, `1` are live cells, and `3` are ghost cells. My class is supposed to count and return all the neighboring live cells of `0`'s and `1`'s. For this array, if I were to print the neighbors it should return

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 2 1 2 1 0
0 2 1 3 3 2 2 0
0 2 2 3 3 1 2 0
0 1 2 1 2 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

instead, it returns

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It would seem it only counts the neighbors up to `1` for any given live cell. Here is my class used to count the surrounding live cells

```
public static int NeighbourCount(int[,] array, int x, int y)
{
    int neighours = 0;

    if (array[x, y] != 3)
    {
             if (array[x + 1, y    ] == 1) { neighours++; }
        else if (array[x + 1, y - 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        else if (array[x    , y - 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        else if (array[x - 1, y - 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        else if (array[x - 1, y    ] == 1) { neighours++; }
        else if (array[x - 1, y + 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        else if (array[x    , y + 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        else if (array[x + 1, y + 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
    }

    return neighours;
}
```

I can't figure out why this only returns `0`'s and `1`'s. Any idea what is causing the issue? Could the issue be how I print the classes return? I print it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(NeighbourCount(array, i, j) + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", ascii));
    ascii.Clear();
}
```

Any solution or idea on whats the issue would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: How is the variable `ascii` defined an filled with values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check all conditions in `if` statements, but in your code the conditions are checked up to the first condition where the value is `true`. Just remove all `else` statements.

```
public static int NeighbourCount(int[,] array, int x, int y)
{
    int neighours = 0;

    if (array[x, y] != 3)
    {
        if (array[x + 1, y    ] == 1) { neighours++; }
        if (array[x + 1, y - 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        if (array[x    , y - 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        if (array[x - 1, y - 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        if (array[x - 1, y    ] == 1) { neighours++; }
        if (array[x - 1, y + 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        if (array[x    , y + 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
        if (array[x + 1, y + 1] == 1) { neighours++; }
    }

    return neighours;
}
```

Check it out: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UQV4Up